# How to pass # in url as a parameter in django 2

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-urls, django-2.0

I am trying to pass a code "Req-2019#000001" Django URL. I want to pass this code as well as normal string and number also in URL as arguments.

```
path('generateBomForSingleProduct/<requisition_no>/' , views.generateBomForSingleProduct, name='generateBomForSingleProduct'),
```

Its work properly but the problem is its add extra **/** before **#**

My URL is now this

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/production/generateBomForSingleProduct/Req-2019/#000001

But I want to like this

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/production/generateBomForSingleProduct/Req-2019#000001

Not an extra **"/"** before my **"#"**

Comment: `path(r'generateBomForSingleProduct/<requisition_no>/' , views.generateBomForSingleProduct, name='generateBomForSingleProduct'),` try this

Comment: Just try not to work brother still gives me an extra / @KostasCharitidis

Comment: Well I cannot reproduce with so little part of code but a quick workaround is to use `replace`. I.e. `your_url.replace('//#', '#')`

Comment: would you please give me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The portion of the URL which follows the **`#`** **symbol is not normally sent to the server in the request for the page**. So, it's not possible to have a URL as **`/production/generateBomForSingleProduct/Req-2019#000001`**

---

#### Workaround

Just modify the url as **`/production/generateBomForSingleProduct/Req-2019/000001`**, so you need to modify the view also

```
# views.py
def generateBomForSingleProduct(request, part_1, part_2):
    unique_id = "{}#{}".format(part_1, part_2)
    # use the "unique_id"
    ...
```

```
#urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    ...,
    path('foo/<part_1>/<part_2>/', generateBomForSingleProduct, name="some-name"),
    ...

]
```

Answer (score 1):

Part after `#` is called fragment identifier, which is used by browsers and never sent to server.

In `http://127.0.0.1:8000/production/generateBomForSingleProduct/Req-2019/#000001` url `000001` is never sent to server. Hence using important part of url after `#` is useless. Better to pass `000001` as query parameters or separate argument.

Comment: So bececaly you trying to say I cannot solve this problem?

Comment: @Antu why you want # in url?

Comment: Because of Req-2019/#000001 is an unic code. I may try another way to solve this problem by not passing code via URL but I just want to know is that impossible to send # via URL?

Comment: @Antu As I said earlier part after # is called as fragment identifier which is only used by browsers and never sent to server.

Comment: @NishantNawarkhede note that this has absolutely nothing to do with Django - not passing the anchor part to the server is part of the HTTP spec itself

Answer (score 1):

Using 'get' would be the proper way to do this. `#` is for html fragments, which are not sent to the server. Why can't it just be

`/production/generateBomForSingleProduct/Req-2019?code=000001` and then you handle everything in the view that way?